# Determining the number of possible combinations of a number to get a specified result

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I came across this question:

Given an integer, determine the number of possible combinations using only 2,3,7 whose sum will give the integer.

Eg:

```
4 - 2  {(2,2)}
9 - 3  {(2, 7), (2, 2, 2, 3), (3, 3, 3)}
```

One way is to iterate through 3 loops and then determine whether the sum is attainable. Here's the code:

```
for( i=0; i<=num/2; i++){
    for( j=0; j<=num/3; j++){
         for( k=0; k<=num/7; k++){
            if(i*2+j*3+k*7 == num) 
                 count++;
}
```

Here count will have the number of sets possible. But this is very inefficient and takes O(n3) time. I would like to know if there is any other efficient way of computing the number of different sets.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem

Answer (score 1):

A dp solution should for this problem should be linear. ([Implemented here](http://ideone.com/vfuBXt))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SZ 5
int memo[SZ+1+7];


int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
    memset(&memo[0], 0, sizeof memo);
    memo[0] = 1;

    for(i = 0; i <= SZ; ++i) memo[i+2] += memo[i];
    for(i = 0; i <= SZ; ++i) memo[i+3] += memo[i];
    for(i = 0; i <= SZ; ++i) memo[i+7] += memo[i];

    printf("%d\n", memo[SZ]);

    return 0;
}
```

1. We start with a 1-D dp array `memo` with ideally infinited size
   (allocated dynamically in practice) of size which doesn't cause out
   of bound for index `SZ + max_num`.
2. Initilize element `0` of this array with 1, because there is 1 way
   to obtain empty_sum.
3. If we can obtain a number `k` in x ways, there are x more ways to
   obtain `k+2`, `k+3` and `k+7`. This is what 3 loops are using.
   (Number_of_ways[{2,3,7}+i] += number_of_ways[i])
4. After all loops are done, **memo[k : 0 - SZ] contains the number of
   ways we can obtain k**.

Giving a complexity of O(k * N) where k is 3 here (2, 3, 7). For constant k, this is linear.

Comment: If n is 5, your formula return 2, which is wrong, it should return 1 only (2 + 3)

Comment: It considers `2+3` and `3+2` different

Comment: I think he is asking for combination, not permutation, and his example is very clear about this

Comment: The author specified that 9 Should return 3

Comment: Hi Mohit, you can remove your old answer and explain your edited answer.

Comment: @cegprakash It is the DP version of the old answer

Comment: @cegprakash Done. I hope this would be more useful for readers.

Comment: Nice solution. @user1677597: This solution is just O(n)! Prefer this one. Replace SZ with your num.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in O(n^2).

Just avoid your last loop.

```
for( i=0; i<=num/2; i++){
    for( j=0; j<=num/3; j++){
        k = num - i*2 - j*3;
        if(k%7==0)
                 count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think for your first loop `num/7` will be a better condition?

Comment: Yes! But it isn't much :)

Comment: @PhamTrung explain why you feel num/7 is better? What if the given number is 7?

Comment: The complexity of the code I've answered is O(num^2/6). The complexity can be reduced to O(num^2/21) if 7 and 3 are used in outer loops.

Comment: @user1677597 because the for loop start at 0, so even if number is 7, it will still be ok, similar for case num/2, and for a for loop from 0 to num/7 and from 0 to num/2 , which is shorter? Just simple math