# What is a good iterative solution for this recursive algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, iteration

**Problem**: Given an array and a target number, *print the number of ways* the target number can be written as a unique combination of elements in the array.

**Example**:

```
array = {1,2,3} target = 4
4 = {2,2}, {3,1}, {1,1,1,1} //numbers can be repeatedly selected from the array.
Ans: 3 ways
```

**Recursive Solution**

```
F(4) = F(4-1) + F(4-2) + F(4-3)
F(4) = F(3) + F(2) + F(1)
...
```

Total sum is the sum of each recursive call to the function with the array value subtracted as the argument.

Conceptually recurrence can be expressed as (ironically as an iteration):

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
   sum+=F(target - array[i]);
```

**Base Cases:**

```
F(0) = 1 //Implies sums to target
F(<0) = 0 //Implies cannot sum to target
```

However, even for a trivial case as above, it results in a StackOverflowError. How best to iterate the solution below:

**Code**

```
public class CombinationSum {

    private int[] array;
    private int target;

    public CombinationSum(int[] array, int target)
    {
        this.array = array;
        this.target = target;
    }

    public int recurSum(int val)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        if(val < 0 )
            return 0;
        else if(val == 0)
            return 1;
        else 
        {
            for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
            {
                sum+= recurSum(target-array[i]); //heavy recursion here?

            }

            return sum;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int target = 4;
        int[] array = {1,2,3};

        CombinationSum cs = new CombinationSum(array, target);

        System.out.println("Number of possible combinations: "+cs.recurSum(target));
    }

}
```

Comment: Just store the values in an array as you go, and look up in the array instead of recalculating.

Comment: sum+= recurSum(**target**-array[i]); it should be sum+= recurSum(**val**-array[i]);

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338929/find-all-ways-to-sum-given-number-with-repetitions-allowed-from-given-set

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489371/determining-the-number-of-possible-combinations-of-a-number-to-get-a-specified-r/23489477#23489477

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo Code

```
F[0]=1;

for(i=1;i<=n;++i){
  F[i]=0;
  for(j=1;j<i++j){
    F[i]+=F[i-j];
  }

}

print F[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in Python.

```
#input is a list A of positive integers, and a target integer n
#output is a list of sublists of A (repeats OK!) with sum n
#permutations will appear
def make_list(A,n):
    A = list(set(A)) #eliminate repeats in A
    L = []
    if n > 0:
        for a in A:
            if type(make_list(A,n-a)) == list:
                for l in make_list(A,n-a):
                    l.append(a)
                    L.append(l)
    elif n == 0:
        L = [[]]
    else: L = -1
    return L

#returns the count of distinct lists in make_list(A,n)
def counter(A,n):
    b = []
    for l in make_list(A,n):    
        if sorted(l) not in b:
            b.append(sorted(l))
    return len(b)
```